# import com.xuggle.mediatool.IMediaReader. package not detected

Tags: java

so i tried to compile the eclipse project given by http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/02/introduction-xuggler-video-manipulation.html but when i do i get the following error:

```
ERROR com.xuggle.ferry.JNILibraryLoader - Could not load library: xuggle-xuggler-io; version: 3; Visit http://www.xuggle.com/xuggler/faq/ to find common solutions to this problem
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no xuggle-xuggler-io in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1681)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:840)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1047)
    at com.xuggle.ferry.JNILibraryLoader.loadLibrary0(JNILibraryLoader.java:265)
    at com.xuggle.ferry.JNILibraryLoader.loadLibrary(JNILibraryLoader.java:168)
    at com.xuggle.xuggler.io.FfmpegIO.init(FfmpegIO.java:74)
    at com.xuggle.xuggler.io.FfmpegIO.<clinit>(FfmpegIO.java:60)
    at com.xuggle.xuggler.io.URLProtocolManager.registerFactory(URLProtocolManager.java:117)
    at com.xuggle.xuggler.io.URLProtocolManager.<init>(URLProtocolManager.java:82)
    at com.xuggle.xuggler.io.URLProtocolManager.<clinit>(URLProtocolManager.java:56)
    at com.xuggle.xuggler.Converter.<clinit>(Converter.java:140)
Could not find the main class: com.xuggle.xuggler.UtilsTest$1. Program will exit.
```

i haven't used java in over a year and i was wondering how would i be able to reinstate the packages?

Comment: This is not an issue about import. I have used this package some time back, if I am correct, you have to create the JNI connection. The code is given by the xuggler team, if my memory is correct

Comment: are you getting UnsatisfiedLinkError too?

Comment: @yohan havent tried creating an jni connection and i think i am getting a link error, are packages things i that should come with source code project? because i have issues with those for other code i copy from internet. =/ i thought they were like imports